# How can I center div, inside other div with bootstrap classes?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, sass

I'm working on a responsive web page using Bootstrap and SASS.

How can I center the **maintext div** and **Logo**, when the screen has smaller size? I've tried a variety of options, such as:

```
@media (max-width: 750px) {

    #maintext {
     margin-left: 0;
     margin-right: 0;

    }
}
```

I also tried to place **maintext div** inside another div **centerhelper**, and to do so:

```
@media (max-width: 750px) {
    .centerhelper {
        left: 50%;
        border: solid blue 2px;
    }

    #maintext {
     left: -50%;

    }
 }
```

But the height of the **centerhelper div** was equal to zero, I tried different "display" CSS for the **centerhelper div** and **maintext div**, but did not succeed.

Here is my HTML code:

```
 <!-- NAVIGATION TOP -->
        <nav class="navbar my-navbar navbar-inverse">
          <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">

     <!-- LOGO -->
              <a href="#" class="my-logo pull-left"><img src="img/Logo.png"></a> 
      <!-- LOGO -->          
               <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              </button>

            </div>
            <div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse pull-right">
              <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li><a href="#"><button class="navbutton active">Home</button></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><button class="navbutton">About</button></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><button class="navbutton">Services</button></a></li>
                  <li><a href="#"><button class="navbutton">Portfolio</button></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><button class="navbutton">Blog</button></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><button class="navbutton lastbutton">Contact</button></a></li>
              </ul>
            </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
          </div>
        </nav>

        <!-- NAVIGATION TOP END -->
        <!-- SHOWCASE -->  
          <section class="showcase">
            <div class="container showcase-content">

<!-- MAINTEXT DIV -->
               <div class="centerhelp"> <div id="maintext" ></div></div>
<!-- MAINTEXT DIV -->                
             </div>
          </section>
        <!-- SHOWCASE END -->
```

And CSS:

```
.showcase {

  background-image: url(...);
  height: 380px;
  width: 100%;

#maintext {
    padding: 0px;
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;

  margin-top: 91px;
  width: 430px;

    h1 {
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
    }
    p {
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you have a working [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pu62oq3m/1/) of your example

```
@media (max-width: 1000px) {
    .centerhelper {
        left: 50%;
        border: solid blue 2px;
     }
     div#maintext {
       text-align: center;
     }
     .navbar-header{
       text-align: center;
     }
    .pull-left{
      float:none!important;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your JSFiddle works perfectly, but after copying it to my CSS, it is not working, I need some time to understand, maybe CSS of some other  HTML elements on my page interfere.

Comment: You can add !important after the style. Ex. text-align:center!important;

Comment: At the moment, I got the same effect as in your JSFiddle with the logo. But the position of the logo is not fully centered, it is close to the center but slightly to the left in your example, and slightly to the right in my case (I forgot to write that the logo has absolute positioning).

Comment: I still haven't got the same effect with the maintext div. Something similar I can  get if I add the line width: 100%, for maintext div after the @media query, but then the text is stretched to the width of the page, and I would like to move the maintext div so that the text remains in the same form as it was. I continue to work on it.

Comment: but in my jsfiddle the maintext div in centered. for absolute positioning you can use 
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;

Comment: YES!!! Thank you, this is what I need!) Still have a problem with the maintext. div, I'll write as soon as I find a solution

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121282/discussion-between-edisoni-1337-and-maxim-velichkin).

Comment: Check the chat and let's talk there because the answer here is correct and we are talking for another thing :)

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try this, This would be in absolute center in all screen sizes. :)

```css
.popup{
  position:fixed;
  left:50%;
  
}
.popup .wrapper{
  position:relative; 
  left:-50%;
  
  /*popup-styles*/
  background-color:#fff;
  padding:10px;
  border:solid 2px #444;
  border-radius:10px;
}

html{background-color:#aaa;}
```

```html
<div class="popup">
  <div class="wrapper">
    
    
       <img src="http://farm4.staticflickr.com/3721/8826906676_501192b1c4.jpg">
         
         
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! But I need the div-s to be centered only when the screen size is small. But I will try to implement this method.

Comment: You can use media queries and make sure that the CSS is run only on small screens. Please mark the Answer as Right if it helped you :)

Comment: @MaximVelichkin check my jsfiddle for what you need.